# Intent called more then once after receiver called

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I'm building an alarm app. When the alarm starts an intent a receiver is started where the "magic" happens. Somehow the `onReceive()` method inside the broadcast receiver is called more then once.

Any ideas why it is happening?

**Edit:**

It is called more then once only if the screen is closed, if the screen is open it does not happen. When the screen close I call this code to open it:

```java
KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock kl = km.newKeyguardLock("MyKeyguardLock");
kl.disableKeyguard();

WakeLock wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | 
                                   PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | 
                                   PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

What am I doing wrong? In the `AndroidManifest.xml` I registered the broadcast reciever using this code:

```xml
<receiver android:name="com.xxx.xxx.myAlarmReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="REFRESH_THIS" />
     </intent-filter>   
</receiver>
```

I'm not sure about the `REFRESH_THIS`. But still, if I change it the receiver is still called more then once.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently debugging an application that had the same behavior.  While the device was on and the service handling the intents was backgrounded it would still accumulate messages.

**Some potential issues you might look out for**:

- If you're using the alarm as an interval timer (via
  [`setRepeating()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), or some less wonderful serial method) the timer
  can go off several times while the [application / service] is not
  running (ie while the device is off - [see the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)).  The result
  being that several messages are queued in the handler, and when the
  application is brought back to the foreground the handler will run
  through the queue - multiple alarm intents will be consumed.
- You're using a class that extends [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingService) to receive the intents, and
  you started your service with `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`.  When the
  service is backgrounded mid-task: it has successfully partially-executed 
  and is interrupted to be paused. When restarted
  the intent is re-delivered and processed a second time.
- [`recycle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#recycle%28%29) your messages - or just extend [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#ExtendingIntentService) instead.

**To debug you may want to**:

- Add an incrementing extra to each intent (via [`addExtra(String, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)) to see if one intent is being delivered multiple times, *or* several intents are being consumed simultaneously.

You should also include code from your receiver in the question.

That's all I've got.